# Can't locate object method "ssl_opts" via package "LWP::UserAgent"

Tags: perl, centos

All related modules are installed and also checked dependencies ..already installed everything even though given below error :

> Can't locate object method "ssl_opts" via package "LWP::UserAgent" on centos 6

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `ssl_opts` method was added in [libwww version 6.00](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/libwww-perl#L255). And the [Centos 6 package](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/) is called perl-libwww-perl-5.833. So, the version of LWP::UserAgent that you have is too old to include that method.